# Add index to appended element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to order items inside a div,I have list fetched dynamically structured like this:

```
<div class="array-placeholder">
<div class="tag">....</div> #index 0 
<div class="tag">....</div> #index 1
<div class="tag">....</div> #index 2
</div>
```

I want to append an element

```
<div class="array-placeholder">
<div class="tag">....</div> #index 0 
<div class="tag">....</div> #index 1
<div class="tag">....</div> #index 2
<li><div class="tag">....</div></li> # index =0 but it should be 3
</div>
```

I tried to solve this like this but the index is always 0

```
newElem.insertAfter($(".array-placeholder").find('.tag').eq((listLength-1)));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `<li>` inside `<div class="array-placeholder">` is invalid HTML

Comment: Inside "eq()" method too much brackets. It should .eq(listLength-1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with jQuery `:last-child` selector like following?

```js
var newElem = '<li><div class="tag">....</div></li>';
$(newElem).insertAfter($(".array-placeholder .tag:last-child"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="array-placeholder">
<div class="tag">....</div>
<div class="tag">....</div>
<div class="tag">....</div>
<div class="tag">las tag</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `insertAfter`, it would be simpler to use jQuery's [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method:

```js
$(".array_placeholder").append(newElem);
```

This will simply tack the new element onto the list as the last child.

Comment: $(".array_placeholder") has other children that are dynamic that I didn't mention but it seems that I found the solution which is finding a way to delete the appended <li>

Answer (score 1):

this will  definitely work while using jquery

```
var newElem = '<div class="tag">....</div>';
$(".array-placeholder").append(newElem);
```